# change the default voice on windows 7 via C# code

Tags: c#, windows-7, voice

I need to change the windows 7 current default voice (Microsoft Anna and an extra German voice is installed) via C# code.

As I am a beginner programmer, it will be difficult for me to find it out on my own.
Any ideas how I can achieve it? Thank you all in advance for the replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows 7 Audio API includes the [SpeechSynthesizer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596245.aspx), you could call for example the [SelectVoice method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.selectvoice.aspx):

> Use the GetInstalledVoices method and VoiceInfo class to obtain the
>   names of installed text-to-speech (TTS) voices that you can select. To
>   select a voice, pass the entire contents of the Name property as the
>   argument for the SelectVoice method. The SpeechSynthesizer object
>   selects the first installed voice that contains name in the voice's
>   VoiceInfo.Name property. The SpeechSynthesizer performs a
>   case-sensitive, substring comparison to determine if the voice matches
>   the name.

Edit: I found [some sample code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckop/archive/2008/07/30/enumerating-tts-engines-using-system-speech-synthesizer.aspx) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 Default Voice (changing) Utility – Path:

Windows

```
 Syswow64

      Speech

           Speechux

                sapi.cpl
```

Answer (score -3):

You can change the speed, volume, and pitch of the voice Narrator uses. and it wont need any C# coding...

Open Narrator by clicking the Start button , clicking All Programs, clicking Accessories, clicking Ease of Access, and then clicking Narrator.

Click Voice Settings, and then make any of the following adjustments:

To select a different voice, click the voice you want to use in the Select Voice box.

For a faster voice, select a number in the Set Speed list. The higher the number, the faster the voice.

For a louder voice, select a number in the Set Volume list. The higher the number, the louder the voice.

For a higher-pitched voice, select a number in the Set Pitch list. The higher the number, the higher the pitch. A higher-pitched voice can make the voice easier for some people to hear.

Narrator is not available in all languages, so if the steps above do not work, Narrator is not available for your language.